# Elevate docx4j from 3.3.0 to newer version, AbstractTableWriterModelRow has been removed

Tags: docx4j

I want to elevate docx4j from 3.3.0 to a newer version.

However, there is an error caused by AbstractTableWriterModelRow has been removed.

I try to dive into release note and git log, but I got very limited info.

Could anyone provide some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current docx4j, we have:

```
public class AbstractTableWriterModel extends TableModel
```

and in TableModel:

```
protected List<TableModelRow> rows;
```

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/table/TableModelRow.java

You can see this in use at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/common/writer/AbstractTableWriter.java#L234

I guess that code replaces AbstractTableWriterModelRow.